# Force keyboard to enter certain digit

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Hey guys I'm developing an application for Market Transactions and stuff, and the client wants to have a condition on the edit text of type number decimal.
He wants the user to enter only number 5 after the dot if the number is a decimal and only one digit after the dot.
i.e.
15
14
1949
12.33 (not accepted)
12.5 (accepted)

so how to do so please give me some hints

Comment: i didn't understand your question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and check whether it works.

```
final String regex = "^\\-?(\\d{0,5}|\\d{0,5}\\.[5]{0,1})$";
((EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned destination, int destinationStart, int destinationEnd) {
            if (end > start) {
                // adding: filter   
                // build the resulting text
                String destinationString = destination.toString();
                String resultingTxt = destinationString.substring(0, destinationStart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destinationString.substring(destinationEnd);
                // return null to accept the input or empty to reject it
                return resultingTxt.matches(regex) ? null : "";
            }
            // removing: always accept
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Here user input is checked to match the regular expression and return the input string if it matches and null if not.

Comment: illegal escape character in string literal

Comment: change it to `^\\-?(\\d{0,5}|\\d{0,5}\\.[5]{0,1})$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this [addTextChangedListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258065/6462890).
You need to append 5 to the editText whenever user inputs a dot.
`flag =0;
_field.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().contains(".") && (flag == 0)) {
                flag = 1;
                _field.setText(_field.getText() + "5");

            } else if (s.toString().contains(".") && (flag == 1)) {

            } else {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    });`
```

Comment: And how can i prevent him from entering any other numbers after it

Answer (score 0):

```
<Edittext
    android:id="@+id/testing"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    >

</Edittext>
```

Then, use InputFilter

```
testing.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{NumberFilter(), new InputFilter.LengthFilter(6)});
//OR
testing.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{NumberFilter()});
```

Create class for NumberFilter implemenets InputFilter

```
public class NumberFilter implements InputFilter{
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            // ignore empty space and not number
            if (!isNullorEmpty(source.toString()) && !isOnlyNumber(source.toString()))
                return "";

            //ignore first .
            if (!source.toString().charAt(0).equals("."))
                return "";

            if ((source.toString().charAt(0) != '8' || source.toString().charAt(0) != '9'))
                return "";

            return null;
        }
    }



// to allow 1 and 1.2
public static boolean isOnlyNumber(String number) {
     return number.matches("(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )");
}

//check empty space or Null
public static boolean isNullorEmpty(String string){
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(string);
}
```